# Differentiability of finite linear maps

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $T\in L(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R^m}).$ Show that $T$ is differentiable at every $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Compute $T'(x)$.

What would be a good way to go about proving something like this? We were told in lecture that we can use the fact that all linear maps from finite dimensions to finite dimensions are differentiable, but I'm not sure which definition of differentiable is best to use here.

Comment: I would suggest using the definition H. Cartan gives in his "Calculus in Banach spaces".  This definition extends to the infinite-dimensional case and is invariant (coordinate-independent).

Comment: @avs what exactly is his definition? Sorry, I don't actually have access to that book right now!

Comment: Do it with all of them, and decide in hindsight which one is your favourite.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli would something like this work?

"$lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{T(x+h) - T(x) - u(h)}{||h||} = 0$

We have $T(x+h) = T(x) + T(h)$, so take $u(h) = T(h)$ to get the result."

Comment: @mizichael, it's actually what you wrote above: even for a general, *nonlinear* (not necessarily linear) function $F$ from one Banach space to another, the derivative $F'(x)$ is a _linear operator_ $A$ such that
$$
||F(x + h) - F(x) - Ah|| = o(||h||).
$$
So, in the special case when $F$ is linear, $A$ turns out to be $F$.

Comment: @avs What is the interpretation of $o(||h||)$ here?

Comment: A function $g(h)$ is *$o(||h||)$ at $h=0$* if:
$$
\lim_{||h|| \rightarrow 0} {|| g(h) || \over ||h||} = 0.
$$
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation\#Little-o_notation#Little-o_notation]

Comment: @avs Ah, I see - thank you! Just one more question - is there a good geometric interpretation of what this is?

Comment: @mizichael, Yes: tangency.  It is actually easier to see in the general case, not just when $F$ acts from one Banach space to another, but when $F$ acts from one manifold, $M$, to another manifold, $N$.

In this general case (and, hence in the special one), $F'(x)$ is a linear transformation from the tangent space of $M$ at $x$ to the tangent space of $N$ at $F(x)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29

Comment: @avs this is super interesting - thank you for the insight!